# How to disable mailto popup in WebBrowser for Pocket PC .NET CF 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, browser, pocketpc

For security reasons, I'm trying to disable the opening of Outlook (or any default mail client) when the user clicks a popup in my subclassed WebBrowser viewing a local html file.  I've tried replacing the DocumentText with a version sans the "mailto:" link references, but this has continuously failed (no matter what I try, it keeps sticking to the about:blank page after setting the DocumentText).

The best solution to my problem would be to completely disable any default mail clients, via the registry or other means, but I am open to anything I haven't tried yet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my security issue by overwriting the html file to contain no "mailto" references.  After the file is replaced, I simply refreshed it:

```
  TextReader tr = File.OpenText(e.Url.LocalPath);
  htmlFile = tr.ReadToEnd();
  tr.Close();
  tr.Dispose();

  if (htmlFile.Contains("mailto:support@website.com"))
  {
      htmlFile = htmlFile.Replace("mailto:support@website.com", @"about:blank");

      //Recreate new file with fixed html
      File.Delete(e.Url.LocalPath);
      TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(e.Url.LocalPath);
      tw.Write(htmlFile);
      tw.Flush();
      tw.Close();
      tw.Dispose();

      Refresh();
  }
```